# Show success message and then redirect to another page after a timeout using PageFlow

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, primefaces, timeout, seam

How can I show a success message and then redirect the user to another page after a timeout of e.g. 5 seconds?

I need this for the login page after a successful login. I tried the following and I can see the warning message on login failure, but not the success message on login success. It shows immediately the target page.

```
public String check(){
      if (username.equals("test") && password.equals("test")) {
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "PrimeFaces rocks!")); 
            return "Success";
        }else{
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"Sample warn message", "Watch out for PrimeFaces!"));  
            return "Failure";
        }
    }
```

I'm using Seam's PageFlow for navigation.

I have a

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

on the login page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, with the code you posted you won't see the FacesMessage before the redirect, you'll see it after the redirect. But also, in order to make that happen you'll need to add a filter, because messages are lost when you redirect. This is the code for the filter you need (don't forget to declare it in web.xml):

```
public class MultiPageMessagesSupport implements PhaseListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1250469273857785274L;
private static final String sessionToken = "MULTI_PAGE_MESSAGES_SUPPORT";

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
}

/*
 * Check to see if we are "naturally" in the RENDER_RESPONSE phase. If we
 * have arrived here and the response is already complete, then the page is
 * not going to show up: don't display messages yet.
 */
@Override
public void beforePhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
    int msg = this.saveMessages(facesContext);

    if (PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE.equals(event.getPhaseId())) {
        if (!facesContext.getResponseComplete()) {
            this.restoreMessages(facesContext);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Save messages into the session after every phase.
 */
@Override
public void afterPhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES ||
            event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS ||
            event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        int msg = this.saveMessages(facesContext);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private int saveMessages(final FacesContext facesContext) {
    List<FacesMessage> messages = new ArrayList<FacesMessage>();
    for (Iterator<FacesMessage> iter = facesContext.getMessages(null); iter.hasNext();) {
        messages.add(iter.next());
        iter.remove();
    }

    if (messages.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    List<FacesMessage> existingMessages = (List<FacesMessage>) sessionMap.get(sessionToken);
    if (existingMessages != null) {
        existingMessages.addAll(messages);
    } else {
        sessionMap.put(sessionToken, messages);
    }
    return messages.size();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private int restoreMessages(final FacesContext facesContext) {
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    List<FacesMessage> messages = (List<FacesMessage>) sessionMap.remove(sessionToken);

    if (messages == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int restoredCount = messages.size();
    for (Object element : messages) {
        facesContext.addMessage(null, (FacesMessage) element);
    }
    return restoredCount;
}
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, and you need to show the message before, then you'll have to something like the following: make the method return void, invoke it through ajax, and after adding the success message invoke some javascript method that will wait a couple of seconds and then make the redirect (maybe by programmatically clicking a hidden button that redirects to next page). 
In my opinion this is not worth the trouble, you will just delay the login process. Anyway user will know tha tlogin succeeded because he will be redirect to home page (or whatever page you send him to)

**EDIT:**
the messages are displayed in the page when the method finishes, so waiting in the managed bean method won't work. after adding the FacesMessage, use

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("waitAndRedirect()");
```

And in your xhtml, you'll need to have a javascript function similar to this:

```
function waitAndRedirect() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        hiddenButtonId.click();
    }, 2000);
}
```

where hiddenButtonId is the ID of a p:button which redirects to home page and is hidden (display:none)

But again, this a nasty approach, in my opinion there's no need to do this, you will just delay the login process.

Comment: Hello @Damian ,
i'm working with ajax, i have tried Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000); it lets the page waiting 5sec but the message shows after the redirect, i just want tto show the message before the redirection with that method thank you!!

Comment: Note that this is a JSF 1.x targeted solution. In JSF 2.x there's a much nicer way using flash scope.

Comment: @Holysh I edited the answer to explain on how to make the message appear BEFORE redirect.

Answer (score 17):

It is one of the utilities of Flash. Instead of

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "PrimeFaces rocks!"));:
```

simply use this code

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Flash flash = facesContext.getExternalContext().getFlash();
flash.setKeepMessages(true);
flash.setRedirect(true);
facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "PrimeFaces rocks!"));
```

Comment: The `setRedirect()` call is unnecessary. Please note that the message will appear in the target page and thus the OP must have a `<p:messages>` over there.

Comment: Hi @BalusC i was waiting your answer :)
yes it works with my code and also with the code provided by user... , but the problem is how can i show the message before redirection then after 5sec for example redirect to another page

Comment: Hi Balus, what's the exact utility of setRedirect?

Comment: @Holysh, displaying a message for 5 secs is not ergonomic because perhaps the user won't see the message or he'll waste 5 secs.

Answer (score 1):

you can not declare MultiPageMessagesSupport  in the web.xml you must declare MultiPageMessagesSupport  in the faces-config.xml. por example:

```
enter code here

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>your.package.MultiPageMessagesSupport</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```