# Why my JSF application doesn't show the context message?

Tags: jsf, redirect, message

I am working with `Prime Faces` and I would like user start in a index page, press a button for call a function (`registrarUsuario`) for reload the index page and show the context message. My problem is my application doesn't show the message.
This is my code:

index.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
...
<h:form>
    <b:commandButton action = "#{registroUsuario.registrarUsuario}" value = "call function"/>
</h:form>
....
```

RegistroUsuario.java:

```
public void registrarUsuario() throws IOException, Exception {
    try {
        //another code
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(":D", "message");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Falla", e.toString());
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, message);
    }finally{
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Primefaces does not preserve Messages through a redirect.

One possibility to cope with this is to add a filter which passes all unrendered messages to after the redirect. This answer provides a solution: [Show success message and then redirect to another page after a timeout using PageFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809772/show-success-message-and-then-redirect-to-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

Because according to the docs [PrimeButton showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml), the button by default is Ajax, so you need to put the update param with the view you want to update, or add the param ajax="false"

```
 <p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" id="ajax" update="growl" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
 <p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" id="nonAjax" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" ajax="false" />
```

Notice how the first option has an **update** attribute, or the second one an **ajax="false"**